# Multiple dtypes in a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data set in a numpy array:

Array 1:

```
[[a, 1, 20]
 [a, 3, 40]
 [b, 1, 20]
 [b, 2, 40]
 [c, 5, 90]]
```

Array 2:

```
[[a, 2]
 [a, 5]]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following: `Array2[0,0]=a`, and `Array2[0,1]=2`
I want to interpolate from the first array to find `a,2,30`.

To do this I'm using `np.where(Array1==item)[0]` which looks for `'a'`, I can't interpolate though because the `dtype` used to import was a string, not an int.

It's been a while since I've used Numpy so if I'm completely in the weeds please let me know.

Comment: What does it mean to interpolate between `'a'` and `2`? And what other dtype would you use for `'a'`?

Comment: What is `a`.  Is it a string?  a variable?  What's the `dtype` of these arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you want to specify an aggregate dtype.

This is explained in detail in the [`dtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) docs.

For example, here's a way to specify that each row has a 1-character string and a 64-bit native float (when you don't care what the field names are):

```
dt = np.dtype('U1, f8')
```

There are of course other ways to write this; read the full page for details.

And, assuming you've read this in with [`loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt), the docs there have a nice example of using such a dtype. For example:

```
>>> s2 = 'a 2\na 5\n'
>>> i2 = io.StringIO(s2)
>>> a2 = np.loadtxt(i2, 'U1, i4')
>>> a2
array([('a', 2), ('a', 5)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U1'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Comment: dt = np.dtype('U1, f8') did not work for me? this behaved like a float. I could not find any reference in the docs